# Spring Security: enable / disable CSRF by client type (browser / non-browser )

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

Spring Security documentation [says](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html#d4e2036):

> "When you use CSRF protection? Our recommendation is to use CSRF
>   protection for any request that could be processed by a browser by
>   normal users. If you are only creating a service that is used by
>   non-browser clients, you will likely want to disable CSRF protection."

What if my service is going to be used by both "browser" and "non-browser" clients such as third party external services, does Spring Security provide a way to disable CSRF exclusively for certain type of clients?

Comment: I would just put a flash program in a browser page, say I'm a non-browser client, and attack the user when they have no CSRF protection.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I am disabling CSRF for trusted clients only, that trust I am establishing thru X509 and SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am sure there is a way to do this in Spring Security XML, but since I am using Java Config, here is my solution.

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class SoapApiConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/soap/**")
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }


    @Configuration
    public static class WebApiConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http        
                .formLogin()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/authentication")
                    .usernameParameter("j_username")
                    .passwordParameter("j_password").permitAll()
                    .and()
                .csrf().disable()

        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you disabling csrf for all the requests ?

Comment: As soon as I disable csrf for one url it is disabled for all the urls

Comment: @amit Yes the above example disables csrf for all the requests, but you can selectively remove the explicit `csrf().disable()` from your configuration. My example is to demo enable/disable csrf for soap(which has typically non browser client) and rest (which usually serve browser clients).

Comment: Your usecase is more fine grained where you want to enable/disable csrf at request level. I think spring would allow that using .antMatcher if you go thru spring official documents. Please let us know if you find something. else I will do some research over the weekend and let you know.

Comment: I am also thinking for the browser and non browser use case.. say for example I want all the requests to /webpages/browser csrf enabled and everything else csrf disable. can we achieve it from your example. I tried but either csrf is disabled for all or enabled for all.. Sure will share if I make any progress...

Comment: Please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498328/selective-usage-of-spring-securitys-csrf-filter

Answer (score 5):

IMHO, there is nothing like that *out of the box*. What I would do in your case, is to have a hierarchy of URL for example rooted at `/api` that would be exempt of csrf. It is easy to configure. In the XML config, you have a normal `<http>` block including `<csrf/>`, you just duplicate it and modify the first block like that

```
<http pattern="/api/**">
    ...
    <!-- csrf -->
</http>
```

As it is first, it will be triggered for any request to `/api` hierachy without using csrf, and all other requests will use it.

In the normal part of the application, you never use the `/api/**` url, and reserve them to non-browser usages.

Then in your controllers, you map them to both their normal url and a copy under `/api` :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({ "/rootcontrollerurl", "/api/rootcontrollerurl"})
class XController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/request_part_url", ...)
    public ModelAndView method() {
        ...
    }
}
```

(of course, `rootcontrollerurl` and `request_part_url` may be blank ...)

But **you** must analyze the security implication of allowing non csrf controlled requests, and eventually exclude controllers from the `/api` hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I used to disable the  CSRF protection on an specific endpoint 
on your appconfig-security.xml add a node with the information of your pattern like the following example:

```
<http security="none" pattern="/sku/*"/>
<http security="none" pattern="/sku/*/*"/>
<http security="none" pattern="/sku"/>
```

Just keep in mind the order is important if you are going to use map all request using the symbol '*' goes first.