# Selective usage of Spring Security's CSRF filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, csrf-protection

**Disclaimer:** My question is somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524470/spring-security-3-2-csrf-disable-for-specfic-urls/29147610) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179940/spring-security-enable-disable-csrf-by-client-type-browser-non-browser/26239302?noredirect=1#comment49059085_26239302), but I have tried all the answers suggested in those threads and already spent few days struggling with the problem.

I am introducing Spring Security 3.2.6 in my existing application (JSP, Servlet only) and I am using Java configuration. My application will be used both by browsers and non-browser clients. I want all the browser requests to URLs (i.e. `/webpages/webVersion/` and `/webpages/webVersion2/`) to be CSRF enabled and all the other requests to be CSRF disabled. Non-browser clients never access above two URLs, whereas the browser application may also access CSRF disabled URLs.

I have tried a variety of options:

1. Enable Spring Security only on the aformentioned URLs:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/","/resources/****").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/webpages/webVersion/****", "/webpages/webVersion2/****").authenticated()
           .antMatchers("/webpages/****").permitAll()
           .anyRequest().anonymous()
           .and()
           .formLogin().loginPage("/webpages/webVersion/login/newLogin.jsp").failureUrl("/webpages/webVersion/login/newLogin.jsp?error=true").loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
           .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/webpages/webVersion/login/loginSuccess.jsp", true).permitAll()
           .and()
           .logout().logoutUrl("/webpages/webVersion/logout.jsp").permitAll()
           .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/webpages/webVersion/404-error-page.jsp")
           .and()
           .csrf();
   }
   ```

   This didn't work as I observe that CSRF is enabled for all of the URLs.
2. Tried using `CSRFProtectionMatcher`:

   ```
   .csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfRequestMatcher);
   ```

   CSRF is enabled for intended URLs only, but even `/resources/**` and `/webpages/**` URLs need to be checked inside matches function.  Seems to be a bit much considering it will be for all requests.
3. Tried using another version of the `configure` method:

   ```
   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
       web.ignoring().regexMatchers(".*?/jsp/(?!webVersion|webVersion2).*?");
   }
   ```

   I am not sure whether I did it correctly but this didn't produce the results I wanted.

---

Which of the above approach is the correct (Spring Security) way of doing what I want? How can I achieve the desired behavior from my Spring Security configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that their was some error with my configuration and finally I achieved the objective using approach 3.. I used below version of the configure function along with the usual `configure(HttpSecurity http)` function..

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring().regexMatchers(".*?/jsp/(?!webVersion|webVersion2).*?");
}
```