# Login issue with Spring and Android client

Tags: android, spring, authentication, jhipster

I generated a project with the jHispter generator and I tried to use an android client to connect to the server. I have a problem with the login part, I don't know how to generate/obtain the csrf-token needed for the login. I saw that the web client sends this token as part of the request.

When I try to access the route from Postman and Android I receive this error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2016-04-02T17:37:42.925+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.",
    "path": "/api/authentication"
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRSF token is generated by the app (by Spring Security) and sent to web browser as a cookie on first page access.

If your API is going to be accessed only by an Android app then you can safely disable csrf in SecurityConfiguration.

If your API is going to be accessed also by a webapp (like JHipster's angular part) you should have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179940/spring-security-enable-disable-csrf-by-client-type-browser-non-browser).